# How do you chain a jquery function to a vanilla selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-backstretch

It's probably simple, but I can't figure it out or word it correctly for search engines. I'm trying not to use jquery where possible for a.performance and b.personal practice.

I am selecting an element

`var container = document.getElementById('container');`

Then I try to chain this jquery method on it

`container.backstretch('url/to/img');`

The jquery plugin I'm using is called [backstretch.js](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/)

Is there an easy way to do this? Or does the answer rely on how the method was written?

Thanks!

Edit:

Console displays this error:

Uncaught TypeError: container.backstretch is not a function

Edit:

`$(container).backstretch('url/to/img');` works. But I don't fully understand it. Is this because jQuery needs to create an object to attach the method to?

Comment: When dealing with jQuery methods and properties, just take your element and reference it as a jQuery object: `var $container = $('#container');`

Comment: @itsgoingdown Just thought of this too haha. It works. Is this because jQuery needs to create an object to attach the method to?

Comment: Yes indeed, sir. Easy sleezy ;-)

Comment: Yes, it's a `jQuery` plugin, it won't work on pure `DOM` object, so you have to wrap that cached `container` DOM object with jquery, and call it on `jquery object`

Answer (score 1):

No sure if there's any performance savings, especially this being an ID selector, but, this is how:

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
$(container).backstretch('url/to/img');
```

Or simply just use:

```
$('#container').backstretch('url/to/img');
```